# Redirect urls with parameters to homepage url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following example urls that i need redirecting to www.example.co.uk

- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?feed=comments-rss2
- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?feed=rss2
- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?cat=518
- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?cat=514
- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?cat=520
- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?cat=521
- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?cat=523
- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?cat=515
- http://www.example.co.uk/wordpress/?p=119

There are many more urls further to this list that all have a wordpress/ notation.

Would I have to write a conditional rewrite for each like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^feed=comments-rss2$
RewriteRule ^/wordpress/?(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=518$
RewriteRule ^/wordpress/?(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk [R=301,L]
```

or is there a rule i can write that redirect all urls that have /wordpress in them to redirect to www.example.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a single rule like would be suffice:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(feed|p|cat)=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wordpress(/.*)?$ http://www.example.co.uk/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure this is **very first rule** in your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Thanks that works! Care to explain what that regEx code means?

Comment: Yes sure this line `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(feed|p|cat)=[^&]+ [NC]` matches `feed` OR `p` OR `cat` query parameters where request URI starts with `/wordpress`. `NC` is for no case comparison. Also `?` in the `http://www.example.co.uk/?` is for stripping out previous query string.