# 301 redirect of home page with query parameters to without query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

```
domain com/?fwcc=1&fwcl=1&fwl=1
```

First of all, I do not know from where this URL came as I tried to search but no answer available, just a guess might be from facebook but I want to get rid of it as it is showing me as duplicate content.

I tried to implement 301 redirect but no success tried different solutions e.g

```
RewriteRule ^/? http://www.domain.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?fwcc=1&fwcl=1&fwl=1$ http://www.domain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

And this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119409/redirect-urls-with-parameters-to-homepage-url) but no success. Please suggest by the way I am using Drupal7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant match against querystring in rule's pattern. You need to match against the_request variable using a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?fwcc=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]
```